# Create double round border for image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want the double round border around my image that is actually square image.

I tried creating. here is the js [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nMusW/) .  The exact that i want is [this](http://puu.sh/aoWyD/856a9bea6b.jpg)

Here is the code

**CSS**

```
.home_boxes {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f1917b;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    border: 5px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px;
    outline: 2px solid #ffffff;
    outline-offset: 9px;
}
img:before {
    border: 5px double #ff0000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    bottom: 10px;
    content: "";
    left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="home_boxes">
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/310x311">
    </div>  
 </div>
```

Please any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nMusW/1/)?

Comment: I tried double border but double border doesnt solve the purpose as i have given link to screenshot already what i need. Inner border i need thick 5px wide and then some psace n then outer border just 1px.

Comment: You are trying to use `img:before`, but that is not supported in all browsers (because pseudo elements created using `:before`/`:after` are supposed to be rendered as if an actual child element was inserted into the element at first/last position – but an `img` can not have child elements in HTML.) You will need to put an extra element around the image, I think – see http://jsfiddle.net/nMusW/5/

Comment: @CBroe add this as answer and I will accept this..

Answer (score 0):

Use `box-shadow`. It can have several values:

```
img {
    /* first white ring */
    border: 5px solid #ffffff;
    /* background 5px ring + ring link border */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #f1917b, 0 0 0 10px #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/T7TQq/) with double circle border.

Answer (score 0):

if the image is not transparent PNG. you can use `padding` and `background` , just like below;

```
img {
    border: 5px solid #ffffff;
   padding:5px; background:blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

demo here ---->  [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/junkie/T7TQq/3/)